# First-order logic and NBG

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that NBG set theory can be viewed as an interpretation of the first-order logic with equality. However, I do not really understand how do I get this interpretation.

As I see it: 
I call variables "classes" and add the class membership relation $\in$. I call a class $x$ a "set" if $\exists y \  (x \in y)$.

But what do I do with constants? Also, there is an empty set and the universal class, and I do not know how to represent them in the form $\emptyset = \dots$ and $V = \dots$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that NBG is an *interpretation* of FOL, it's that NBG is a *theory in* FOL, in the same way that e.g. the theory of rings is a theory in FOL.

The language of NBG has a single binary relation, "$\in$," and no constants or functions. So there's no need to interpret those (any more than we would demand that a ring understand what "$<$" means, say). As to $\emptyset$ and $V$, those aren't *constant symbols*, but rather *definable elements* - e.g. NBG proves that there is a unique $x$ satisfying $\forall y(y\not\in x)$, and a unique $z$ satisfying $\forall w(\exists u(w\in u)\implies w\in z)$. We refer to these as "$\emptyset$" and "$V$," but this is done *outside* the formal language.

Comment: Thank you! But I have two more questions:

1. If $\varphi(A_1, ..., A_n, x)$ is a formula, then we have the following axiom $$ (\forall A_1)\dots(\forall A_n)(\exists B)(\forall x)[x \in B \Leftrightarrow \varphi(A_1,... A_n, x)] $$ But what do we mean when we write $S = \{x : \varphi(A_1,... A_n, x)\}$? One of those classes $B$?

2. What do we mean by saying that we _fix_ some class?

Comment: @user379994 Re: your first question - actually, you can prove that there is *exactly* one $B$ with that property (remember that the only elements of classes are sets, and we have Extensionality). So there's no choice between "one of those" classes that needs to be made. Re: your second question, I'm not sure - where are you seeing this?

Comment: It is from the book "Set theory and the Continuum problem" Part 1. Ch. 2. Here is the [screeshot](http://imgur.com/f7Ak0zH). I also do not understand how can we can have collections of objects which are not subclasses of $V$.

Comment: @user379994 Ah. The OP is describing the construction of a *model* of NBG. To build a model of NBG, the most obvious thing to do is to pick a class $W$ and try to build a model around it so to speak. "Fix a class" means the same thing as "fix a number" - we have some symbol $\sigma$, and we pick some appropriate object to be denoted by it (a number, a function, a class satisfying some properties, . . . ). Note that this takes place *inside* some bigger universe of mathematics, which the author is presumably leaving informal.

Comment: So NBG is a first-order theory (i.e. a first-order predicate calculus with some proper axioms). When I interpret this theory (fix some class $V$) s.t. all axioms are true, I get a model of NBG. Is it correct?

Comment: @user379994 Yes, that's correct. Same with the theory of rings - if you give a set with some appropriate structure in which the ring axioms are true, you get a model of the theory of rings (that is, a ring).

Comment: These question and answer are important. I thought that, e.g., $\emptyset$ is a 'functional symbol' with zero arity. You said that 'definable symbols' are outside the formal system. Then I have a semiformal proof of statement $\vdash (\exists ! x)(\forall y)(y\notin x)$ where I used $\emptyset$. How to correct it to be fully formal? (7th page https://goo.gl/WViV5e ) I mean how (if it is possible) to use formal system without definitions? Just what one or two examples.

Comment: I mean 'skolemization' is the possible answer to OP's question.

Comment: @GeorgyDunaev While there is no symbol for the emptyset in the language of ZFC, it is still "safe to use": adding symbols for *defined entities* isn't going to change what theorems you can prove (see e.g. "expansion by definitions"). Precisely, suppose $T$ is a theory in the language $\Sigma$ and $\varphi(x)$ is a formula in $\Sigma$ such that $T\vdash\exists x\varphi(x)$. Then let $T'=T\cup\{\varphi(c)\}$ in the expanded language $\Sigma\sqcup\{c\}$; we can show that $T'$ is *conservative over* $T$, that is, that for all $\Sigma$-sentences $\psi$, $T'$ proves $\psi$ iff $T$ proves $\psi$.

Comment: In fact, this is true in a very strong way: any model $M$ of $T$ can be expanded to a model $M'$ of $T'$. So for example, ZFC proves "$\exists x(\forall y(y\not\in x))$", that is, "There is an empty set." We can add a symbol "$\emptyset$" to our language to denote such a set, and add to ZFC an axiom "$\forall y(y\not\in\emptyset)$" describing its behavior; the resulting theory ZFC' will prove example the same sentences in the language of set theory as ZFC. So while definable elements need not have symbols in the original language, such symbols can always be *added* in a benign way.

Comment: (And, in fact, we can give an easy if tedious procedure for converting any proof from $T'$ (of a sentence in the original language $\Sigma$) to a proof from $T$, and verify the correctness of this procedure in an extremely weak theory; so this is all as constructive as could be wanted.)